# How to deal with possible duplicates in an Ember store?

Tags: ember.js

My Ember apps retrieves model objects from an API that can contain duplicates on successive calls.

I want to store my objects like this:

```
myController.store.createRecord('myModel', myModelObject).save()
```

Unfortunately, when a duplicate occurs, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The id XXX has already been used with another record of type MyApp.MyModel.
(fonction anonyme)ember.js:3866
```

I couldn't figure a way to recover gracefully from that error. I tried:

```
myController.store.createRecord('myModel', myModelObject).save().catch(myFailureCallback)
```

but the failure callback doesn't get called and the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the record is already loaded into the store

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_recordIsLoaded

`store.recordIsLoaded('myModel', myModelObject.get('id'))`